# HTTP polling vs WebSocket for very small payloads that don't change often

Tags: http, websockets, resources, polling

In our team we are currently discussing which technology makes more sense for an upcoming feature - HTTP polling vs WebSocket.

To give some context:

- We are developing a TV streaming application (server and mobile clients).
- We currently have about 60 TV channels.
- On some channels we need to prohibit the user from seeking within/across ads.
- For this, the mobile client needs to know where ads are in the current program - let's say that a given program contains at most 10 ads and the client only needs to know the start and end timestamp of each ad, no additional info.
- The information where the ads occur in a stream is pushed to one of our services directly from the TV companies. The information may arrive "just in time", so we need to update the clients quite frequently to make sure they have current data.
- We already have a WebSocket connection in place to track viewer numbers for each channel, i.e. the WebSocket service already knows which user is watching which channel.

So, I think this leaves us with two main solutions:

1.) The client "polls" the server every few seconds to ask for an updated list of ads for the current channel. As the data is minimal (60 channels x 10 ads for the current program x 2 timestamps per ad) it should be easy to keep in memory, maybe using memcached or the like. Since the data will only change every few minutes in practice, if we use HTTP caching (`ETag`), most responses would actually be empty.

2.) The service receiving the ads from the TV companies pushes them to the WebSocket service which in turn forwards them to all users that are currently watching the affected channel.

I am one of the client developers and as such I have a strong preference for HTTP polling. It fits into the app architecture a lot easier, parsing the responses is trivial and error handling methods are already in place. To use the WebSocket, I would have to change more app code, parsing all different kinds of messages coming out of a single WebSocket is a bit messier and there is practically no error handling.

I also would have thought that putting the current data into memcached or the like would be trivial - and preferable to having to push stuff around between services, but I am being told that the server load would be too much to handle. At the moment I think we rarely have more than about 10 000 concurrent users, but let's be optimistic and hope for 100 000 within a year.

Given all this, which solution makes more sense?

I hope I have described the situation in just enough details to allow for a proper evaluation!

Thanks a lot for any advice!

Comment: one of these sends a few kilobytes of data every few seconds, and the other does not. So which one do you think makes more sense? Think in terms of what you want the computer to do: as little useless work as possible.

Comment: @user253751 Of course I want the computer to do as little as possible. But I also want to keep the development effort as low as possible, while still getting a robust solution. Considering that live streaming involves the transfer of several hundred kilobytes every few seconds (in general, the manifest file is reloaded every four seconds, in addition to the actual media files) and that this load is handled just fine by the streaming server I was thinking that another small HTTP request might be a sensible solution... But, in any case, thanks a lot for your input!

Comment: HTTP polling is more resource-intensive on the server-side than WebSockets. I don't think this is a decision to take from the client side because it affects the sizing of the backend. Polling is also inefficient since some calls will result in nothing to do. Now imagine thousands of clients doing this "small" request nearly at the same time, every X seconds. The peak could be interesting to see.